# AssertionError in matplotlib animation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

My problem is following:
I'm taking a data from files and want to make an animation of four plots at the same time: two colourbars and two lines.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as anim
import sys

begin = float(sys.argv[1])
end = float(sys.argv[2])


dataCl = np.loadtxt("file1.txt")
dataSS = np.loadtxt("file2.txt")
datajSR = np.loadtxt("file3.txt")

ibegin = 0
iend = 0
for i in range(len(dataCl[:,0])):
    if np.abs(dataCl[i,0] - begin) < 1e-9:
        ibegin = i
        iend = i
        while abs(dataCl[i,0] - end) >= 1e-9:
            iend = iend + 1
            i = i + 1
        break


fig = plt.figure()
f, axarr = plt.subplots(2, 2)
temp = np.zeros((10,10))
Qs = axarr[0,0].imshow(temp,cmap = plt.cm.OrRd)
El = axarr[0,1].imshow(temp,cmap = plt.cm.OrRd)
SS, = axarr[1,0].plot([],[])
jSR, = axarr[1,1].plot([],[])

def init():
    Qs.set_array(temp)
    El.set_array(temp)
    SS.set_data([],[])
    jSR.set_data([],[])
    return Qs,El,SS,jSR,

def animate(i):
    a = 0
    b = 0
    dataQ = np.zeros((10,10))
    dataE = np.zeros((10,10))
    for j in range(100):
        if b >= 10:
            a = a + 1
            b = 0
        dataQ[a][b] = dataCl[i,2*j + 1]
        dataE[a][b] = dataCl[i,2*(j+1)]
        b = b + 1
    Qs.set_array(dataQ)
    El.set_array(dataE)
    SS.set_data(dataSS[ibegin:ibegin+i,0],dataSS[ibegin:ibegin+i,1])
    jSR.set_data(datajSR[ibegin:ibegin+i,0],datajSR[ibegin:ibegin+i,1])
    return Qs,El,SS,jSR,

ani = anim.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func = init, frames = iend-ibegin,interval=25, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

After running it shows these messages:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1413, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 236, in resize
    self.show()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 239, in draw
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 421, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/figure.py", line 904, in draw
    self.canvas.draw_event(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 1544, in draw_event
    self.callbacks.process(s, event)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/cbook.py", line 262, in process
    proxy(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/cbook.py", line 192, in __call__
    return mtd(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/animation.py", line 273, in _end_redraw
    self._post_draw(None, self._blit)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/animation.py", line 220, in _post_draw
    self._blit_draw(self._drawn_artists, self._blit_cache)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/animation.py", line 235, in _blit_draw
    a.axes.draw_artist(a)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 2008, in draw_artist
    assert self._cachedRenderer is not None
AssertionError
```

I cannot find a mistake in my code ;(

Answer (score 0):

The error message might be backend and platform specific. As the error message seems to point to the blitting mechanism, you might want to try setting `blit=False` in `FuncAnimation`. Also, you might try some other backend to see if the problem persists. (Knowing your platform and `matplotlib` version might also help.)

**Update:** If setting `blit=False`, trying another backend, and updating `matplotlib` does not help, then a few suggestions:

1. Try to see manually if you code works with the initial data (`init(); animate(0); fig.savefig("/tmp/test.png")`) - if it throws an error, there is a static plotting problem to fix.
2. Now you initialize the plot twice (first in the code, then in `init`), you can take one away (e.g. do not define `init_func`)
3. Initializing the plots with `[],[]` leaves the scale uninitialized. You should probably use `set_ylim`, `set_xlim` with the plots and `vmin`, `vmax` keywords with the `imshow` images when you initialize them. (This could possibly have something to do with the exception you get!)

Comment: Matplotlib 1.1.1rc
Linux Mint 13 Maya

Comment: @Hi4ko I suggest you install the newest release (1.3.1 today, 1.4.0 next month) and retry. `matplotlib` is under very active development, and a lot of old bugs have been ironed out.

Comment: Installing the newest release didn't help ;( It still creates two figures, first is absolutely empty and the second one is only with axes ;(

Comment: @Hi4ko: Well it is always a good idea to update, so you did not lose anything :) However, see the edit for more suggestions.